# Unique: Email large group with addresses VISIBLE to all

Tags: email

How to email more than 100 people at once while keeping email addresses VISIBLE for all to see?

- Tricking it by putting some addresses in the To row and others in the CC row, doesn't work.
- Splitting the email into two separate groups doesn't work because then each person only sees the half of the email addresses that was included in their copy.

Comment: Even with your modification, this is too broad for here. It's nothing to do with a web application. Even if we limit to webmail clients, the advice would probably be different for each. It's a longshot, but [communitybuilding.se] _might_ be the right place for this question. Honestly, it seems that you've fallen prey to an "XY problem". You think the solution to what you need is keeping everyone's email address visible, but what you should really be doing is focusing on the original problem.

Comment: I apologize for wasting everyone's time - I'm new here and thought I was following the guidelines.

Comment: Using Yahoo mail - but didn't specify as I'm open to any email that lets me send to more than 100 people at once. Guess I provided too much detail (which I can see how it looks like an XY problem) in an effort to avoid replies to use Yahoo Groups, Google Groups, etc.. If I didn't need to keep everyone's email address visible to everyone, I wouldn't have an issue I needed help with.  So, again - sorry for my clutter.  I do appreciate those that tried to help

Comment: I suggest you install thunderbird and connect your email account to it.  Then you can make an address book group and put the name of the group in the To field.  If my instructions are too terse, go to the thunderbird forum for more step-by-step guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this.

This is how community and group emails were done 20 years ago. The problem is that somebody will move and they will continue to get lost dog emails forever. These systems of email lists have no way to reliably add, remove or change emails on the list.

Look for solution where people can subscribe and unsubscribe, and that limit the ability to email everybody only to members of the group. Some require somebody to be a moderator to approve additions to the group, other solutions  don't.

Comment: Normally, yes - in this case list is kept accurate and current                                In group you suggest, how can updated document be sent to each member quarterly?

Comment: @Tammy You still haven't told us which program or web service this is related to.